# How can I check in a Bash script if my local Git repository has changes?

Tags: git

There are some scripts that do not work correctly if they check for changes.

I tried it like this:

```
VN=$(git describe --abbrev=7 HEAD 2>/dev/null)

git update-index -q --refresh
CHANGED=$(git diff-index --name-only HEAD --)
if [ ! -z $CHANGED ];
    then VN="$VN-mod"
fi
```

Is there some kind of boolean check if there has been changes since the last commit, or how can I really test if there are new changes to my local repository?

I'm doing all this for a version creation script (that I found somewhere here).

Comment: What's wrong with `git status` ?

Comment: @karlphillip: It does a lot of processing that you don't really need.

Comment: @karlphillip it's a "porcelain" command, that means: not appropriate for use in script because the output is designed to be read by humans and may change (between versions or due to localization)

Answer (score 236, accepted):

What you're doing will almost work: you should quote `$CHANGED` in case it's empty, and `-z` tests for empty, which means no changes. What you meant was:

```
if [ -n "$CHANGED" ]; then
    VN="$VN-mod"
fi
```

A quote from Git's `GIT-VERSION-GEN`:

```
git update-index -q --refresh
test -z "$(git diff-index --name-only HEAD --)" ||
VN="$VN-dirty"
```

It looks like you were copying that, but you just forgot that detail of quoting.

Of course, you could also just do this:

```
if git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
    # No changes
else
    # Changes
fi
```

Or if you only care about the "something has changed" case:

```
if ! git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
    VN="$VN-mod"
fi
```

Using `--quiet` has the benefit that Git can stop processing as soon as it encounters a single diff, so it may not have to check your entire work tree.

Comment: Hi, that was one of the best answers on a question, you just gave me all information that I needed and that others my need as well :).

I'll just need the last one, "something has changed" :) and you were right, I copied it.

Comment: The amazing [bash completion script](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/completion/git-completion.bash;hb=HEAD) seems to use `git diff --no-ext-diff --quiet --exit-code` to determine the dirty state.

Comment: @mjs: That's indeed a great place to look for things like this! The `--no-ext-diff` option is good for safety (in case someone has configured an external diff driver), though the `--exit-code` shouldn't be necessary, since it's implied by `--quiet`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me as it doesn't report untracked files

Comment: @Jefromi The last two examples dont work correctly unless you run a "git update-index -q --refresh" before them. Specially if you did a git fetch, pull or checkout before them.

Comment: If you want to check a directory, not a full repo, you can use this command: `git diff-index --quiet HEAD -- path/to/dir/` – that's the script in question with added dir

Comment: why use `--`? can it be replaced with `.`(which means current directory)?

Comment: `git diff-index` reports changes even if only file modification times have changed (and not their contents). If you `touch` a file, it will report modification that running `git status` will reset. Using `git status` as below is better.

Comment: This solution indeed produces false positives sometimes, as described by @Sampo

Answer (score 521):

Using [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status):

```
cd /git/directory
if [[ `git status --porcelain` ]]; then
  # Changes
else
  # No changes
fi
```

Comment: The best answer, a shame the answers from the 'shell and git architects' are more highly voted.

Comment: Right, the other answers are correct, but this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This is great as it takes into account unversioned files and also using porcelain, it should be more compatible with different git versions.

Comment: Simplest and best.

Comment: To ignore untracked files: **if [[ `git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no` ]]; then**

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check if stdout of the command is empty?

Comment: For checking local changes ->

```if [[ $(git status --porcelain | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]; then
  echo CHANGED
else
  echo NOT CHANGED locally
fi```

Comment: **What this code does:** Execute `git status --porcelain` see if output is not empty. If so that means there are changes present.

Comment: It's odd that this answer wouldn't have more upvotes; it's straight out of `man git-status`, and it's the simplest/most straightforward answer. What is the advantage of the more complex approaches?

Comment: For me, the conditional always stepped into the "No changes" case even when the git status was non-empty. It was fixed by using `if [ -n "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then`.

Answer (score 22):

This works too:

```
if [ $(git status --porcelain | wc -l) -eq "0" ]; then
  echo "   Git repo is clean."
else
  echo "   Git repo dirty. Quit."
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 21):

*Although Jefromi's answer is good, I'm posting this just for reference.*

From the Git source code there is a `sh` script which includes the following.

```
require_clean_work_tree () {
    git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null || exit 1
    git update-index -q --ignore-submodules --refresh
    err=0

    if ! git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules
    then
        echo >&2 "Cannot $1: You have unstaged changes."
        err=1
    fi

    if ! git diff-index --cached --quiet --ignore-submodules HEAD --
    then
        if [ $err = 0 ]
        then
            echo >&2 "Cannot $1: Your index contains uncommitted changes."
        else
            echo >&2 "Additionally, your index contains uncommitted changes."
        fi
        err=1
    fi

    if [ $err = 1 ]
    then
        test -n "$2" && echo >&2 "$2"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Comment: For reference, and if I read this right, `$1` is a string naming a task you want to run and `$2` is a string optionally containing a custom error message on failure.  For example, call it like `require_clean_work_tree deploy "Skipping deploy, clean up your work tree or run dev-push"`

Answer (score 13):

I've looked up dozens of Stack Overflow answers and none of them seemed to suffice my expectations. That is, the script should error if:

- there are any differences between the current local state and the `origin/master` (including: changes to existing files; new uncommitted and committed files, and file deletions), or
- `master` has commits that haven't been pushed yet to `origin/master` .

The final script can be used like this:

```sh
if ! (git diff --exit-code origin/master..master > /dev/null) \
  || ! (git diff --exit-code master > /dev/null) \
  || ! [[ -z "$(git status --porcelain)" ]] ; then
  echo "Your local repo has some changes that aren't pushed to origin/master ."
  exit 1
fi
```

Explanation:

- `git status --porcelain` will render list of files that aren't committed yet. Wrapping this with `[[ -z "$(...)" ]]` makes it error if the command has returned a non-empty string.
- `git diff --exit-code master > /dev/null` will error if your current committed repo state differs from `master` branch.
- `git diff --exit-code origin/master..master > /dev/null` will error if your current `master` branch differs from `origin/master`.

This is useful if e.g. you want to make sure your repo is probably safe to be deleted/cleared up.

Why is that better?

- answers that rely only on `git diff --exit-code ...` will not error if you have new uncommitted non-stashed files;
- answers that rely only on `git status --porcelain` will not tell you that you have commits that are not pushed yet to the remote.

Comment: Replace `master` with `main` everywhere if a newer repo (that uses `main`).

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem, but I had to check for added files also. So I did the following:

```
cd /local/repo
RUN=0
git diff --no-ext-diff --quiet --exit-code || RUN=1
if [ $RUN = 0 ]; then
    RUN=`git ls-files --exclude-standard --others| wc -l`
fi

if [ $RUN = 0 ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: note: `--quiet` option implies `--exit-code`, so `git diff --no-ext-diff --quiet` should be enough (at least on the latest git).  Refer: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---quiet

Answer (score 8):

**`git status` is your friend**

Change to the Git directory for `git status` to work:

```
cd c:/path/to/.git
```

Set a variable to set the work tree so you don't get 'This operation must be run in a work tree' error:

```
WORKTREE=c:/path/to/worktree
```

Capture the `git status` output in a Bash variable

Use `--porcelain` which guarantees to be in a standard format and  parsable:

```
CHANGED=$(git --work-tree=${WORKTREE} status --porcelain)
```

If -n (not null), we have changes.

```
if [ -n "${CHANGED}" ]; then
  echo 'changed';

else
  echo 'not changed';
fi
```

Comment: This has the benefit of detecting untracked files as well.

Answer (score 7):

The OP's question is more than 9 years old now. I don't know what `man git-status` said then, but here's what it says now:

```
--porcelain[=<version>]  
Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the 
short output, but will remain stable across Git versions and regardless of user 
configuration. See below for details.  

The version parameter is used to specify the format version. This is optional and 
defaults to the original version v1 format.
```

This suggests that the `--porcelain` argument is well-suited to testing the status of a repo for changes.

Wrt the OP's question, *"Is there some kind of boolean check if there has been changes since the last commit, or how can I really test if there are new changes to my local repository?"*

I don't think that `bash` has boolean data types *per se*, but this may be close enough:

```sh
[ -z "`git status --porcelain`" ] && echo "NULL-NO DIFFS" || echo "DIFFS EXIST"
```

This can be re-cast as a `if-then-else` form for a script, or executed as-is fm the CLI while **in the git repo folder**. Otherwise, use the `-C` option with a path spec to the repo of interest:

```sh
git -C ~/path/to/MyGitRepo status --porcelain
```

---

#### Addendum:

1. Some advise using the `-u, --untracked-file` option to avoid reporting status on files one wishes to ignore. Note this comes with an unfortunate *side-effect*: files that are **newly added** are not statused either. The option is useful in **some situations**, but consider it carefully before using.

Answer (score 7):

my 2 cents:

```
git status --porcelain | head -1
```

returns only one line instead of a long list

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about changes to the *working tree* and not the *index* then use the code below. As a reminder for folks who are not as in-tune with specific git terminology, this means all changes have been `git add`ed and doing `git diff` will show nothing. (`git diff --cached` will show the changes you have `add`ed but not yet `commit`ed.)

```
if [[ $(git status -z | cut -z -b 2 | tr -d '[:space:]\000') ]]; then
  # Changes
else
  # No changes
fi
```

`git status -z` is `--porcelain` with null delimiters instead of line breaks. `cut -z -b 2` gets only the second byte from each of those (which represents changes to the working tree). `tr -d '[:space:]\000'` removes all whitespace and null bytes leaving only characters that are changes to the working tree. Apart from that it works the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149786/1858327), if this is *empty* then there are *no changes in the working tree*.

This is useful because changes in the index (that you `git add`ed) are "saved" in a sense. You can screw around with the working tree and get them back.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it...

```
CHANGES=`git status | grep "working directory clean"`
if [ ! CHANGES -eq "" ] then
    # do stuff here
else
    echo "You have uncommitted changes..."
fi
```

Comment: I like using git status, but it is better to use --porcelain in scripts and compare the result to an empty string for no changes, since it is guaranteed not to change in an incompatible way across versions.

Answer (score 1):

This works nicely. It will also list the files affected:

```
if git diff-index --name-status --exit-code HEAD;
then
    echo Git working copy is clean...;
else
    echo ;
    echo ERROR: Git working copy is dirty!;
    echo Commit your changes and try again.;
fi;
```

Comment: if you don't want to see the diff `git diff --no-ext-diff --quiet --exit-code` also does the work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice set of Bash script functions that check if there is a diff, prints it to the user and prompts the user if they would like to commit changes before deployment. It is built for a Heroku and Python application, but it needs little change for any other application.

```
commit(){
    echo "Please enter a commit message..."
    read msg
    git add . --all
    git commit -am $msg
}

check_commit(){
    echo ========== CHECKING FOR CHANGES ========
    changes=$(git diff)
    if [ -n "$changes" ]; then
        echo ""
        echo "*** CHANGES FOUND ***"
        echo "$changes"
        echo ""
        echo "You have uncomitted changes."
        echo "Would you like to commit them (y/n)?"
        read n
        case $n in
            "y") commit;;
            "n") echo "Changes will not be included...";;
            *) echo "invalid option";;
        esac
    else
        echo "... No changes found"
    fi
}

deploy(){
    check_commit
    echo ========== DEPLOYING TO HEROKU ========
    git push heroku master
    heroku run python manage.py syncdb
}
```

You can copy from Gists on: https://gist.github.com/sshadmand/f33afe7c9071bb725105

Answer (score 1):

The solution with Ansible:

```
- name: Bootstrap checks
  block:
  - shell: "git status --porcelain"
    register: git_status
  - fail:
      msg: "Please clean git status: {{ git_status.stdout }}"
    when: git_status.stdout != ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @storm_m2138 comment to @RyanMoon's answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149786/509614)) I am using the following in `Powershell`.

```bsh
function hasChanges($dir="."){ $null -ne (iex "git -C $dir status --porcelain --untracked-files=no") }

gci -Directory | ?{ hasChanges $_ } | %{ Write-Host "$_ has changes" }
gci -Directory | ?{ hasChanges $_ } | %{ iex "git -C $_ add -u"; iex "git -C $_ commit -m"Somemthing" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another working method:

```
if git diff --exit-code; then
 echo there is no change
else
 echo there is changes
fi
```

However `git diff` doesn't check staged changes. `git status` shows staged changes

Answer (score -2):

```
nano checker_git.sh
```

paste this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "First arg: $1"

cd $1

bob="Already up-to-date."
echo $bob

echo $(git pull) > s.txt
cat s.txt
if [ "$(cat s.txt)" == "$bob" ]
then
echo "up"
else
echo "not up"

fi
rm -rf st.txt
```

---

## run `sh checker_git.sh gitpath`

Comment: Downvoted because this has nothing to do with the question here.